# A program to print numbers from 1 to n in triangular wave form without using extra space

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to print numbers from 1 to n(say 10) in a triangular wave form.Here is the code -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //code
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[3][10];
    int r=1,c=0,dir=-1;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            arr[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        arr[r][c]=i;
        if(r==2 || r==0)dir = -dir;
        if(dir==1)r++;
        else r--;
        c++;

    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(arr[i][j]==0)
              cout<<"  ";
            else cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The **output** of this code is

```
    2       6       10
  1   3   5   7   9
        4       8
```

Is it possible to solve this problem with using an array?

Comment: Why not outputting a `' '` character everytime you hit a `0` in your array when printing?

Comment: Define 'in sine wave form'. Do you mean you want to print *sin(x)*?

Comment: @EJP I have mentioned the required output pattern

Comment: Something wrong with an `if` statement?

Comment: FWIW this is mostly down to the poor resolution but your example is actually a triangle wave :P

Answer (score 0):

Replace the body of the third cycle with

```
if (arr[i][j] == 0)
    cout << ' ';
else
    cout << arr[i][j];
cout << ' ';
```

Indeed, you want to print the number, but if it is 0, you want to print a space

Comment: @abhishekgupta Now try it without an array.